# Swift UIPageViewController not loading initial view

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController as my initial view. I load up 3 view controllers, and then I try to set one of them as the initial one.

```
let defaultView = UIViewController()
print("called")
defaultView.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
let viewController = NSArray(object: defaultView) as [AnyObject]
self.setViewControllers(viewController, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

It appears this code does nothing. The view is simply black and that view controller isn't loaded. Strangely, if a swipe right or left, I see some of the other UIViewControllers that I made. Any ideas why? I can post more code if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. I was overriding `setViewControllers` without calling `super`.